# Update currently used app

Tags: android, user-interface, alarmmanager

I am currently experimenting with AlarmManger and I have manageed to make it run in the background and I am also able to make a toast, but what I have not figured out is how am I supposed to edit something in my UI?

Example:
I have my MainActivity, the my code inside the BroadcastReceiver is called every minute and know i want to make some changes to the UI, like for example to write in a Text "AlarmManger has fired x - times" (X would be a counter)

Right know my question how can i make my alarm go off every lets say 10s and not on TIME_KICK as it is registered in the receiver.
Hope you understand it!

Could anyone assist me in my situation?

My MainActivity

```
       package..
       imports[]


    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AlarmReceiver lAlarmReceiver = new AlarmReceiver(this);

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,0,alarmIntent,0);
        findViewById(R.id.btnStartCounting).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                start();
            }
        });



    }

    public void start(){
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 6;
        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),interval,pendingIntent);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    Context mContext;
    public AlarmReceiver(Context mContext){
        this.mContext=mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences` to do this.

In your broadcast receiver, increment your preference:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    int count = sharedPreferences.getInt("count", 0) + 1;

    editor.putInt("count", count);
    editor.commit();
}
```

In your activity, set your `TextView` `onResume()` and register a `OnPreferenceChangeListener` to change it `onSharedPreferenceChange()`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    TextView mCount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        mCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        mCount.setText(Integer.toString(mSharedPreferences.getInt("count", 0)));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if(key.equals("count")){
            mCount.setText(Integer.toString(mSharedPreferences.getInt("count", 0)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, so in this case i would have to implement my broadcastreceiver in an extra class, which will then require an reference to my Activity, but when i try to do so i get "...alarmReceiver has no default constructor" 

I have update my new code

Comment: Why do you need to pass in your context when you construct your receiver? What is wrong with the context that is passed in to `onReceive`?

Comment: Because than it says "can't resolve getSystemService"

Comment: You did read the second question, right? What is wrong with the **context** that is **passed in** to `onReceive`?

Comment: I have but I really do not get it.

Comment: public void onReceive(**Context context**, Intent intent)

Answer (score 1):

Can you please update the question with some code?

You can do something like this

(Do you need an exact code that checks how many times it's called?)

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        int s= 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


          checkFiredTimes();


        }
public void checkFiredTimes(){

//Code that checks how many times is AlarmManager called
//Every time it is called
s++;



Toast.makeText(this,"AlarmManager has fired "+s+" times",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}

    }
```